# Typescript - stop the destruction of a component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, destroy

I have an angular application with 2 main components(let's call them comp A and comp B).At any given time there is  a random number of As and Bs initialized.
Each component has its own "data" variable that he obtains after initializing.

I want to implement a way of checking , at the moment of destruction of a component, if "data" has changed from its initial value.If it has, i want to inform the user and give him 2 options: leave the page without saving or stay on the page.

As a solution i made a copy of the initial "data" and i plan to check , at the destruction of the component, if the data has changed, eventually stopping the destruction of the component.

The question is: Is there a way of stopping the destruction of a component?

I know i have the option to use canDeactivate guard.I can't really use that since the components may not be initialized form route.

Comment: No, but the solution wouldn't work anyway. You can listen to the `beforeunload` event and then initiate the check.

Comment: beforeunload is triggered when the page is closed.I need something that  triggers when the component is unloaded.Is there a way to assign beforeunload to components?(from what i've seen, window.beforeunload takes a callback from my component)

Comment: The destruction of the component is the result of something. You want to react to that event, whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

component-before destroy is a proposed addition to angular. 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20713

Attached is a workaround using metaprogramming and async/await.

[image: Before Destroy]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Route guards` in Angular Application to guard Angular Routes.

`canDeactive` route guard will be called every time when you try to change your angular route and prevents the route change if it returns false.

You can follow this article to create `Route guards`

[`Can Activate and Can Activate Child` Route Guard](https://scotch.io/courses/routing-angular-2-applications/canactivate-and-canactivatechild)

[`Can Deactivate` Route Guard](https://scotch.io/courses/routing-angular-2-applications/candeactivate)